# GRASS GIS: Showing displaying a raster map

Tags: grass-gis

I am trying to understand GRASS GIS to model the transport of solute.

I followed the example of the GrassGIS manual and set up a region within a XY projection. I also used r.mapcalc to generate a raster map. Now I want to display the raster map. But when I execute

```
"d.rast map=phead@PERMANENT bgcolo=red"
```

the console shows

```
"GRASS_INFO_ERROR(18956,1): Field <zone> missing                                 
GRASS_INFO_END(18956,1)".
```

Well, how do I display the raster map?

Comment: What do you get if you run "r.report map=phead@PERMANENT" for example? Just to see if there is an issue with the raster.

Comment: Try a `d.erase`, then again `d.rast  map=phead@PERMANENT bgcolor=red`

Comment: Thank you markusN, now it works.

Comment: (I have written it up  as a regular answer, feel free to accept it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the GRASS GIS display monitor remembers the list of maps which you have displayed.
In your case, one map may no longer exist while the monitor doesn't "know" that.

Solution:

Run `d.erase` to clean the list of maps in the monitor.

Then run again `d.rast  map=phead@PERMANENT bgcolor=red`.